# HTML5 video not loading in chrome, but works when the developer console is opened up

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, html5-video

I am working on a web app for a client, and there is a problem with the HTML5 video tag.

The problem is that the video won't load in chrome, but works on Safari, Firefox and IE.

So I start debugging in chrome, but I found out that if I refresh the page with console opened, the video would load. But when I close the console and refresh, the video would not load...

Here are the few things I have tried:

Have multiple type of videos, in mp4 and webm.
in componentDidMount, replace the video with the same code.

But none seems to work...

```
<div class="Top">
    <div class="video-container BGVideo">
        <video id="videobg" class="video-background" preload="true" loop="" autoplay="" poster="/img/azzura.jpg">
            <source src="/img/azzura.mp4">
            <source src="/img/azzura.webm">
        </video>
        <div class="video-overlay"></div>
        <div class="video-content">
            <div class="BGContent">
                <div class="scrollDown">
                    <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: Possible solution: Open `Developer Console` > Press `F1` > Scroll to `Network` > Check `Disable Cache (while DevTools is open)`. There might be some caching issues in your code. Without extra code we will not be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my problem was that I have autoplay enabled, but with chrome's new policy, autoplay isn't allowed unless it's the video is muted, so adding the muted attribute fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me.

Completed parameters `loop="false"` and `autoplay="false"` as you had them emptied e.g. `loop=""`, etc.

```html
<div class="Top">
    <div class="video-container BGVideo">
        <video id="videobg" class="video-background" preload="true" loop="false" autoplay="false" poster="">
            <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="video-overlay"></div>
        <div class="video-content">
            <div class="BGContent">
                <div class="scrollDown">
                    <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: those attributes are of boolean type. this means they are true when they exist and false if left out. `loop="false"` sets loop to `true`, not `false` in valid html/browsers.