# Html 5 - Background video not working only on chrome without Muted tag.

Tags: html, google-chrome, background

I'm adding a background video with sound.

The code works perfectly on all browsers expect Google Chrome.

Initially, the video does not load at all. However, if muted attribute is added to the  tag it starts working or without the muted attribute if the console is opened and page is refreshed then the video is loaded properly with sound, otherwise not.

However the same code is working on Firefox, Microsoft Edge, UC Browser.

I've tried 2 different approaches both have the same problem, **Background video on chrome either does not work at all or Muted attribute needs to be added in order for the video to appear.**

Approach 1:

```
<video autoplay muted>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

If I remove the muted attribute from video then it stops working on chrome (Still works on all other browsers)

Approach 2:

```
     <body>
     <section id="home-sec"  class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0soX6uwHbk', containment:'self', mute:false, autoPlay:true, loop:true, opacity:1, showControls:false, showYTLogo:false, vol:50}">
         <div class="overlay"  >
            <div class="container" >
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                      <h1>VIDEO GROUND </h1> 
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
                        <h4>Cnsectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

          </section> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!--Jquery CDN-->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js"></script> <!--Youtube Script-->

       </body>
```

In this approach too if I change the data-property="mute:true" then the code works on chrome. Otherwise not.

My google chrome version is: Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Similar Questions:" [HTML5 video not loading in chrome, but works when the developer console is opened up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702236/html5-video-not-loading-in-chrome-but-works-when-the-developer-console-is-opene)"

I've tried to use the same code mentioned by a user. Again, works on firefox but not on chrome.

Also, I have used different versions of chrome to test. All versions have the very same problem.

Comment: have you tried toggling the sound with js? (using an onclick or on load event?)  some sample (adaptable) code here .. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_muted

Comment: Google has now forced it where anything that plays sound without the user interacting in the page first will just break. I understand partially the reason they've done this but I don't fully agree cause it breaks a lot of things including rainymood :( as long as you can get a user to click into the page first then run sounds they will play. Maybe add a script that listens for first click and trigger everything? I know sounds kinda dumb, especially since YouTube still gets to auto play their audio.